# Problema al incluir una animacion de un logo en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, animación

resulta que estoy desarrollando una app que lleva primero un Splash Screen, a lo que he querido hacer que el logo se desplaze de abajo hacia el centro de la activity, pero al depurar la aplicacion en mi telefono la animacion no se aprecia, he utilizado el siguiente codigo:

```
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.move_up);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.startAnimation(anim);
```

El siguiente es de un XML en anim:

```
<translate
    android:duration="900"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    />
```

¿Hay alguna otra forma de realizar la animación? La verdad soy primerizo en android

Comment: Hola, creo que olvide esa parte lo siento, lo que quiero saber es si hay otra forma de hacer la animacion.

Comment: Listo, gracias por los comentarios soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Todos lo fuimos alguna vez, por eso te lo comenté para que lo vieras nomás

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas, que tal si probas

Creas dentro de res/anim un xml que se llame rotar_mover_abajo

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true">
    <!-- Rotamos -->
    <rotate
        android:duration="1200"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

    <!--  Mueve hacia abajo -->
    <translate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="80%p" />
</set>
```

Cambialo con tus valores

y de codigo usa

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.rotate_move_down);
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
img.startAnimation(anim);
```

Creo que el rotate hace el truco ahi y es por eso que no te anda

Debería funcionar, me avisas :)